# Soldering Lines VS Using Wire to join two points on veroboard

Tags: soldering

While using a vero/strip board, when you have to join two points is it better to make a line of solder from the first point to the second OR to use a jumper/component leg to join them together.

At my university, everyone seems to prefer making lines of solder.While it looks cool, I personally think that it's a waste of time and solder, especially when ICs become involved. I'm also not very good at making lines:).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Untill you are working in Mhz range technically that makes no difference. Personally i hate these veroboards, i prefer simple copper clad boards on whitch you can cut your traces with exacto knife and/or join points with wire. You win a big ground plane this way.

Comment: I thought Veroboard was strip board, not pad per hole prototyping board?

Comment: @Cybergibbons- Well as far as I know, Veroboard is a company and they make all kinds of prototyping boards. Where I am they call everything Veroboard, even stripboard:).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally I'm not so fond of those strip boards: I think they give you more limitations than freedom in making connections. I use veroboard with a pad per pin, where you have to make all connections yourself. For that I use 0.8 mm tinned wire which I solder in Manhattan fashion, i.e. vertical and horizontal lines, and right angles. Bridges can be made on the component side. This way you don't have to bother about all these strips going all the length of the board, and which you must avoid making contact with.

[image]

You can still try to draw traces of solder tin, but the surface tension will work against that, unless you supply ridiculous amounts of tin. Even when I want to connect two adjacent pads I bend a pin/wire flat to bridge the gap, and flow solder over it.

An advantage of working with wire is that you can attach a test probe to it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I also usually use pad per pin boards but they're usually square pads, so I suppose the surface tension is less. So for adjacent pads making a bridge is fine, but if it were for two far away points its preferable to just use wire right?

Comment: @Ammar - "preferable" is a strong word, it's not a law. Basically I agree that it's waste of solder. Square pads are easier to bridge with solder, yes.

Comment: I actually became really frustrated when I had to make solder lines adjacent to each other while soldering an IC bed because one line sometimes joins with another and it makes a mess. Thanks for clearing that up for me.